# How can I prove HTTP POST Method is not Idempotent?

Tags: java, http

Is there anyway to prove Http POST Method is not idempotent from below sample code

Sample Code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/event", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json")
public void printEvent(@RequestBody Request request, HttpServletRequest httpRequest) throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.println("HttpRequest: "+httpRequest.getHeader("session")+" & Request: "+request.toString());
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    System.out.println("HttpRequest: "+httpRequest.getHeader("session")+" & Request: "+request.toString());
}
```

Comment: Is this a homework question? Why do you care whether this function is idempotent or not? (hint, it *is* idempotent, but only for some definitions of idempotency).

Answer (score 0):

Being NOT idempotent is a "contract" that the HTTP method like **POST** agrees upon.

The developer writing the back end code can certainly break the contract by making a **POST** request idempotent.
The sample code provided does exactly that. The controller only does one thing - returning a view called "Greetings from Spring Boot!"

The same idea applies to other HTTP methods as well.
If the developer writing the backend controller handling **GET** request in a way that changes the database (create an entity in a database in the **GET** controller directly), the **GET** request will not be idempotent anymore even though the contract says otherwise. It is absolutely a bad practice.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, loaded above POST. /message multiple times but Im not seeing any differnce in response. Can we add something to above code and print what is changing in resource as request being NOT Idempotent

Comment: @ThirupathiSoora I am a little confused about what you are trying to do. According to your sample code, there is no resource being changed in any way.

Comment: May be I'm confusing with aboev sample code, Please ignore that. Can we programatically prove POST is NOT Idempotent?

Comment: You make it sound that having a idempotent implementation of POST "breaks a contract". This is not the case.

Comment: @JulianReschke making an idempotent implementation of POST just doesn’t make sense to me. There are more suitable http methods to make idempotent request. Could you please elaborate on when it is necessary to make a post request idempotent?

Comment: Any complex search form will use POST to circumvent URL size constraints, no? In any case, POST is not *required* to be not idem-potent.

Comment: @JulianReschke That could be an option. But I still want to avoid this whenever possible. Just did a little research on this matter cos I forgot. The modern browsers' URL limit is over 60k ish bytes. Old IE indeed supports only 2048 bytes. Google's search is using GET request, I think that kind of search is pretty complex.  I need to do more research on whether there is a way to use GET for very complex search exceeding the url limit without using POST. Thank you for the chat. if you know the answer now, please let me know.